# mysql count with right join return some wrong values

Tags: mysql, join

I have a problem with count in a right join, with this code i can count how many visites have a video

```
SELECT video_id, COUNT(video_id) AS Views FROM fm_views GROUP BY video_id ORDER BY Views DESC;
```

It returns the following example.

```
video_id    Views
1668306      10
21041317      4
3845          2
13796095      1
16808537      1
11170454      1
```

This is right count, now i put the example 2 that is the wrong count

```
SELECT fm_video.*, IFNULL(COUNT(fm_views.video_id), 0) AS Views FROM fm_views RIGHT JOIN fm_video ON fm_video.video_id = fm_views.video_id GROUP BY fm_video.video_id ORDER BY Views DESC, id DESC;
```

This is the problem, now i get that (Simplified version without zero values)

```
video_id    Views
1668306      10
21041317      4
3845          >>4<< This is the problem
13796095      1
16808537      1
11170454      1
```

Now i get 4 Views in video 3845 when i have only 2 entries with that video_id after the right join, the rest of values are OK, but i think that when i have more entries in the database, i will get more problems with this wrong values

I cant find any helpful with this simple query like format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `right join` quite hard to follow. `left join` seems more natural because it keeps all rows in the first table.  Also, `COUNT()` cannot return `NULL`.  So, this is the query:

```
SELECT vd.*, COUNT(vw.video_id) AS Views
FROM fm_video vd LEFT JOIN
     fm_views vw
     ON vd.video_id = vw.video_id
GROUP BY vd.video_id
ORDER BY Views DESC, id DESC;
```

If this is returning unexpected results, then it suggests that you have bad data, or your expectation is wrong.

For the first possibility, I would suggest validating that `fm_video(video_id)` is the primary key on the table (or at least unique).  You can also run this code to see if there are duplicates:

```
select video_id
from fm_video
group by video_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

You should also check that `video_id` has the same type in both tables.

Comment: Oh man, crap, i got duplicated 3845, for that i got 2 + 2 views, thx its really help, im blind lol ;) Now i set video_id as unique id in fm_videos

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you `select *` you will see some empty `fm_views` rows they are being counted somehow, add the `WHERE` filter, and rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT fm_video.*, IFNULL(COUNT(fm_views.video_id), 0) AS Views 
FROM fm_views 
RIGHT JOIN 
fm_video ON fm_video.video_id = fm_views.video_id 
WHERE fm_views.video_id is not null
GROUP BY fm_video.video_id ORDER BY Views DESC, id DESC;
```

you just need to filter out the null rows

```
WHERE fm_views.video_id is not null
```

This happens if the joined tables have different row numbers
that's why you have the correct count on 2 rows

** please vote up and mark as accepted answer if you find it helpful **